# how to compare filename of date and time between two folders

Tags: embedded-linux

i have two folders both are in different directories.(example ~/folder1/00) (example ~/folder2/01).00 folder contains set of images .am copying 00 folder of images to 01 folders.now i want to compare two folders(00 and 01) each filename along with date and time.if time and date are not same i want to equal the date and time of both images..how should i read and compare both folders of file name along with date and time one by one ..can any one give suggestion for this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://github.com/sa2ajj/dups/blob/master/dups.py, feel free to adapt to your needs

Comment: my task was based on linux